# Was a real hologram of Homer Simpson used at Comic Con 2014?

Tags: technology

At the San Diego Comic Con 2014, [there was what they call an hologram of Homer Simpson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRyHvgHW-wU), but is this a real hologram? Or was it, perhaps, just a projection on the wall? I thought that the hologram technology was far from those kind of impressing results!? If it's really hologram technology, how does it work?

Comment: A rear-projection screen is likely, but I can't find any information with a casual search as to how this particular projection was achieved.

Comment: You might find this really interesting http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GBucCNH78q4

Comment: For those who don't want to follow the YouTube link, it is another animated character appearing on stage in a music video.

Answer (score 3):

It was likely the [Pepper's Ghost effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper's_ghost), used several times since 2006 to project figures on-stage. (Gorillaz in 2006, [Tupac in 2012](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/04/16/tupac-hologram-av-concepts_n_1429316.html) and 2013, and Michael Jackson in 2014.

Calling this effect a "hologram" is common, but a misnomer: (http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/behind-screen/why-billboard-music-awards-michael-706269)

> The imagery of Jackson -- and previously Tupac during his "performance" at Coachella in 2012 -- was actually created with an old magician's trick using a mirror, a 2D effect known as "Pepper's Ghost."

Since the Pepper's Ghost technique has been sufficient to produce this effect in the past, there is no reason to posit a technological leap for this instance.